# Looking for a java library or algorithm for efficiently implementing the second Chebyshev function

Tags: algorithms, libraries

Does anyone know of a java library or algorithm for efficiently implementing the second Chebyshev function?

To be clear, I'm refering to this expression:

$$\vartheta(x) = \sum_{p \le x}\log p$$

$$\psi(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\vartheta\left(\sqrt[m]{x}\right)$$

where $\vartheta(x)$ is the first Chebyshev function and $\psi(x)$ is the second Chebyshev function?

Thanks very much,

-Larry

Comment: There is a Perl library that has this function, [chebyshev_psi](http://search.cpan.org/~danaj/Math-Prime-Util-0.26/lib/Math/Prime/Util.pm).